# En un fichero .bat al usar "choice" hay alguna forma de que todas las posibles pulsaciones de teclas que no hayas definido causen la misma salida?

Tags: batch

Lo que quiero hacer es, básicamente, un "else". Escribir las salidas para las pulsaciones que yo defina y que la pulsación de cualquier otra letra (letras no aceptadas) genere una respuesta común(un mensaje de error)

```
@echo off
echo Bienvenidos al cambiador de extensiones y Copia de Seguridad
:menu
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo Por favor, elige la opcion que desees...
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo 1. Hacer copia de seguridad de ficheros .html
echo 2. Cambiar extension .html a .xml
echo 3. Cambiar extension .xml a .html
echo 4. Salir
CHOICE /C:1234 /N /T 15 /D 4 /M "Pulsa 1, 2, 3 o 4"
if %errorlevel%==1 goto tecla1
if %errorlevel%==2 goto tecla2
if %errorlevel%==3 goto tecla3
if %errorlevel%==4 goto tecla4
goto tecla5

:tecla1
echo Has elegido "Hacer copia de seguridad de ficheros .html"
cd C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\Documentos
mkdir Copias
xcopy C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\Documentos         
C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\Documentos\Copias
goto menu
:tecla2
echo Has elegido "Cambiar extension .html a .xml"
cd  C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\Documentos
rename *.html *.xml
goto menu
:tecla3
echo Has elegido "Cambiar extension .xml a .html"
cd  C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\Documentos
rename *.xml *.html
goto menu
:tecla5
echo Error
goto menu
:tecla4
echo Has elegido "Salir"

pause
:FIN
```

Este es el código que tengo escrito, mi objetivo es que el choice detecte cualquier otra pulsación que no sean las 4 que tengo definidas y salte al mensaje de error (etiqueta tecla5).